# May I say "She's normal, >except she's beautiful<"?

Tags: prepositions

I was writing something here about a girl and I wanted to say something like "she's a normal person, except she's beautiful", like in French "sauf qu'elle est belle"... I'm not quite sure this is correct. Is this phrase grammaticaly correct, and does it make sense at least? If not, what's the correct way of saying this?
Cheers!

Comment: The actual translation is *except that she's beautiful*, which is noticeably better.

Answer (score 3):

You can say

> She's a normal person, except she's beautiful

And it would be grammatically valid. However, it would be better in spoken form than written form because it feels like something is missing. So to improve the phrase just a little bit, I would say

> She's a normal person, except **that** she's beautiful

Or as an alternative

> She's a normal person, except **for the fact that** she's beautiful.

Comment: Should we place the comma ? Is it compulsory? what about using "although / though /whereas/..."

Comment: I don't think the comma is mandatory, but it certainly helps to break up the two parts of the sentence here. We can't really use any of the other contrast words you suggest, though we could consider "aside from the fact that" or "other than that".

Comment: I think, since there is no contrast, we must use theme; Although we want to express that it is exceptional and not ordinary. Am I right ?

Comment: It is more that we are reducing from our original opinion. Consider: she is 100% normal. Oh, but she's beautiful, so I suppose she's 80% normal. That is what "except that" (and the other linking phrases I mentioned) serve as.